# Nodejs Discord Bot Server Crashes After "Duplicate Key Error" from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm new to MongoDB and I have a Discord bot made with Nodejs that stores movie recommendation submissions from members of a discord server, the server stores the data sent over into a MongoDB database(using Mongoose). I'm trying to prevent duplicate records in the DB, setting the mongoose Schema property "unique" to true  helps but whenever anyone submits a movie title that's already within the DB, the server just throws a duplicate key error and crashes, how do I prevent duplicate entries and at the same time prevent the server from crashing when it occurs, and instead maybe just send a reply to the user that the movie already exists in the DB?

My movie submission handler:

```
if(command.includes('sendreclink!')){
        const arr = message.content.split('!')
        console.log(arr[1], arr[2])
        const movieTitle = arr[1].trim().split(' ').map(word => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)).join(' ')
        const movie = new Movie({title: movieTitle , link: arr[2]})
             await movie.save()
            message.reply(`${movieTitle} has been added to the list`)
        
      }
```

My mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_KEY)

const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, unique: true, require: true},
    link: {type: String, unique: true, sparse: true}
  });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

Error message in node console when duplicate entry is sent:

`MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.movies index: title_1 dup key: { title: "American Movie" }`

I tried setting the Schema unique property to true and dropping my DB and starting from scratch.

Comment: I think movie.title field is already  duplicated to prevent this error delete duplicate fields i.e. movie.title from your collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could put some of your code into
a try-catch block, like this

```
try {
  await movie.save();
} catch(ex) {
  console.log(ex)
}
```

This way, even if there's an error, your server wouldn't crash

Comment: I knew it had to do with some error handling, this worked for me, thank you!